# How to use Ionic variables.scss $color in scss file?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

By default Ionic provides the following colors:

```
$colors: (
  primary: #EF5A28,
  secondary: #f5911e,
  danger: #f53d3d,
  light: #f4f4f4,
  dark: #222,
  favorite: #69BB7B,
  darkgraycustom: #333333,
  mediumgraycustom:#666666,
  lightgraycustom : #b2b2b2
);
```

this is easy for use when we are directly bind to DOM using `color="primary"`, but if I want to use in my .scss file then how to access the color in this list?

For example if I want my border to be the primary color? Something like `border:1px solid $color.primary`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
.some-class {
  color: color($colors, primary, base);
}
```